# Discrete uniform circular distribution

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

1. Have a distribution of a discrete number N of angular values in the interval [0:360]
2. Map these N values onto a unit circumference.
3. Automatically determine the two values between which all other values are.

Is there a general solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to compute the mean angle, subtract this from all your angles, getting a result between -circle/2 and circle/2 (where eg circle is 2pi if you are using radians) and take the range to be (mean-angle + the min of these, mean-angle + the max).

This could fail in at least two ways: you might fail to find a mean angle (whats the mean of north, east, south, west?) and the min and max could be -circle/2 and circle/2 respectively, so your range would be the whole circle.

I think the 'proper' way to compute the mean angle is to turn all the angles into unit vectors, take the average of these and use atan2 to find the orientation of the mean vector; this is the mean angle. But note that in the n,e,s,w example, the average unit vector would be 0,0 and atan2 would return nan.

If you're using a C (ish) language the math library function remainder is handy for normalising angles; remainder( a, circle) will be between -circle/2 and circle/2.